# Sql efficient query from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I've two tables `tbl_data` and `tbl_user_data`

**Structure** of `tbl_data`

```
id (int) (primary)
names (varchar)
dept_id (int)
```

**Structure** of `tbl_user_data`:

```
id (int) (primary)
user_id (int)
names_id (int)
```

`tbl_data.id` and `tbl_user_data.names_id` are foreign key

I've situation where I've to pick 25 **random** entries from `tbl_data` which is not served earlier to particular user. So I've created a `tbl_user_data` which will store `user_id` and `names_id`(from `tbl_data` which is already served).
I'm bit confused, how to query on behalf of this or is there any other way to do this efficiently ?

**Note:** `tbl_data` have more than 5 million entries.

So far I've written this but it seems its not right.

```
SELECT td.names, td.dept_id
FROM tbl_data AS td
LEFT JOIN tbl_user_data AS tud ON td.id = tud.names_id
WHERE tud.user_id !=2
ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 25
```

Comment: plus the mysql tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

First ... you need the `LEFT JOIN .... IS NULL` pattern to pick out your not-yet-served items. You'll need to mention the user id in the ON clause to get this to work correctly.

```
SELECT td.names, td.dept_id
  FROM tbl_data AS td 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_user_data AS tud    ON td.id = tud.names_id
                                   AND tud.user_id = 2
 WHERE tud.id IS NULL
 ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 25
```

Second, `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ...` is a notoriously poor performer on a large table. It has to select the *entire* table, then sort it, then discard all except 25 items from it. That's massively wasteful and will never perform decently.

You can make it a little less wasteful by sorting just the `id` values, then using them to get the other information.

This gets your 25 random ID values.

```
                 SELECT td.id
                   FROM tbl_data AS td 
                   LEFT JOIN tbl_user_data AS tud    ON td.id = tud.names_id
                                                    AND tud.user_id = 2
                  WHERE tud.id IS NULL
                  ORDER BY RAND( )
                  LIMIT 25
```

This gets your names and dept_id values.

```
  SELECT a.names, a.dept_id
    FROM tbl_data AS a
    JOIN (
                 SELECT td.id
                   FROM tbl_data AS td 
                   LEFT JOIN tbl_user_data AS tud    ON td.id = tud.names_id
                                                    AND tud.user_id = 2
                  WHERE tud.id IS NULL
                  ORDER BY RAND( )
                  LIMIT 25
         ) b ON a.id = b.id
```

But, it's still wasteful. You may want to build a randomized version of this tbl_data table, and then use it sequentially. You could re-randomize it once a day, with something like this.

```
 DROP TABLE tbl_data_random;
 INSERT INTO tbl_data_random FROM
 SELECT * 
   FROM tbl_data
  ORDER BY RAND()
```

That way you don't do the sort over and over again, just to discard the results. Instead, you randomize once in a while.

Comment: thanks. From Nolan movie "Once an idea has taken hold of the brain it's almost impossible to eradicate" :)  I was stuck on the idea randomizing and saving data in different table, but it is a really good idea to show random entries on the day basis.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on names_id and user_id. Why is user_id varchar?
If need to be varchar and is varchar very long, create partial index on user_id.
You can use EXPLAIN to see what index use your query.

Comment: my bad. user_id is also int, I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not selecting anything from the tbl_user_data, you can use exists instead:

```
SELECT td.names, td.dept_id
FROM tbl_data AS td
where exists (
    select 1
    from tbl_user_data AS tud 
    where td.id = tud.names_id
    and tud.user_id !=2
)
ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 25
```

Index on tbl_data(id) and tbl_user_data(names_id, user_id) will help.